# Iterating Coroutines and awaiting results

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a situation where I need to dispatch an indeterminate number of network calls known only at runtime. Each call returns a list. As each is returned, I need to combine these lists in to a single merged list. I am using coroutines to do this.

The problem I am having relates to the fact that I do not know how many network calls the app will need to make. To address this, I am using a loop to iterate over the list of calls at runtime:

```
private suspend fun fetchData(params: List<Interval>): List<Item> {

    val smallLists = mutableListOf<Deferred<List<Item>>>()
    val merged = mutableListOf<List<Item>>()

    for (index in 0 until params.size) {
        val param = params[index]
        // loop stop iterating after this call is dispatched
        smallLists[index] = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            fetchList(param)
        }
    }

    for (index in 0 until smallLists.size) {
        merged[index] = smallLists[index].await()
    }

    return merged.flatMap { it.toList() }
}

private fun fetchList(param: Interval) : List<Item> {
    return dataSource.fetchData(param)
}
```

What happens in this code is that it enters the first loop. The `params` list is correct. It dispatches the first query, and this query returns (I can see this via a Charles proxy).

But this is where everything just dies. The app does nothing with the network response and the loop terminates (i.e. there is no second iteration of the loop).

I know that everything else is intact because I have an alternate version that does not include looping. It just does two queries, awaits their results, and returns the combined list. It works fine, except that it won't handle a dynamic runtime situation:

```
private suspend fun fetchData(params: List<Interval>): List<Item> {        
    val list1 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        fetchList(params[0])
    }

    val list2 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        fetchList(params[1])
    }

    return list1.await() + list2.await()
}
```

Probably a simple solution here, but I don't see it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
smallLists[index] = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        fetchList(param)
    }
```

Your `smallLists` is empty, so you can't access index `index`. Change it like this

```
smallLists.add(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        fetchList(param)
    }
)
```

Note that you can call `awaitAll()` on your list of `async`s as well, to simplify your code:

```
private suspend fun fetchData(params: List<Interval>): List<Item> {

    val smallLists = mutableListOf<Deferred<List<Item>>>()

    for (index in 0 until params.size) {
        val param = params[index]
        // loop stop iterating after this call is dispatched
        smallLists.add(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
            fetchList(param)
        }
    })

    val merged = smallLists.awaitAll()
    return merged.flatMap { it.toList() }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. Not sure how the code would change with awaitAll(). Would you mind adding that to your answer?

Comment: Great answer. Thanks very much!